# Kazam crashed, convert .mux file to .mp4

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, video-capture

I was recording a 2+ hour long full screen stream of a game (Company of Heroes) and I stupidly and accidentally closed Kazam before it was complete and to ask me where I wanted to save it.

I have found it's already saved everything to a .mux file (my settings was set so that it converts it as a h264 stream into an .mp4 file)

Since Kazam uses GStreamer, How can I use gstreamer to process it to a playable .mp4 format?

this occurred on Ubuntu 16.04

EDIT: I want to add that I really want to save this video file (need sound included too) a high priority for me.

Comment: Ever figure out how to fix this?

Comment: nope :/ still waiting.

Answer (score 0):

```
github.com/bookkojot/mp4fixer
```

This tool solves exactly this problem. Worked for me. There are a few simple steps involved, instructions are enclosed. You need a short properly saved video on the same machine with the same kazam to use as input so it knows what the headers should look like. And you get the mp4.

Comment: have 4 GB file. It never completes.